# Java text file size (before file is closed)

Tags: java, file, filewriter, file-writing

I am collecting full HTML from a service that provides access to a very large collection of blogs and news websites. I am checking the HTML as it comes (in real-time) to see if it contains some keywords. If it contains one of the keywords, I am writing the HTML to a text file to store it.

I want to do this for a week. Therefore I am collecting a large amount of data. Testing the program for 3 minutes yielded a text file of 100MB. I have 4 TB of space, and I can't use more than this.

Also, I don't want the text files to become too large, because I assume they'll become un-openable.

What I am proposing is to open a text file, and write HTML to it, frequently checking its size. If it becomes bigger than, let's say 200MB, I close the text file and open another. I also need to keep a running log of how much space I've used in total, so that I can make sure that I don't get close to 4 TB.

The question I have at this point is how to check the size of the text file before the file has been closed (using FileWriter.close()). Is there a function for this or should I count the number of characters written to the file and use that to estimate the file size?

A separate question: are there ways of minimising the amount of space my text files take up? I am working in Java.

Comment: A separate question should really be a separate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a writer which counts the number of characters written and use that to wrap your `OutputStreamWriter`.

**[EDIT]** Note: The correct way to save text to a file is:

```
new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream( file ), encoding ) ) );
```

The encoding is important; it's usually "UTF-8".

This chain gives you two places where you can inject your wrapper: You can wrap the writer to get the number of characters or the inner `OutputStream` to get bytes written.

Comment: ok, thanks. i will try this. how can i be know how many bytes a character requires?

Comment: If you process english web pages, each character takes one byte. The UTF-8 encoding is pretty compact. But you can also wrap your `FileOutputStream` which gives you the bytes instead.

Comment: ok. i will try experimenting with this. the way i am going to count characters (maybe this is not the right way) is to keep a running total by using a Java string length method on every string that I write to the file

Answer (score 4):

I continuation to Aaron's answer. You can use [CountingOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html): just wrap your FileOutputStream using CountingOutputStream and you will be able to know how many bytes have you already written.

Answer (score 3):

To minimize space, you could [zip](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) your text files with Java. Why not add each file to a zip after closing it. After zipping, you could check the size of the zip to see your your cumulative storage consumption.

Answer (score 3):

HTML will easily compress with a high compression ratio.  Consider using a [GZIPOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) to "minimzie the amount of space" your text files take up.

Answer (score 2):

Did it occur to you to count how many bytes you write to the file?

Comment: i guess this essentially what i want to do, and i guess i do this by counting the number of characters written to the file, as suggested by Aaron.

Comment: Yes, I voted for Aaron's answer too. I think that's the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class TestFileWriter {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fileWriter= new FileWriter("test.txt");
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            fileWriter.write("a very long string, a very long string, a very long string, a very long string, a very long string\n");
            if ((i%100)==0) {
                File file=new File("test.txt");
                System.out.println("file size=" +  file.length());
            }
        }
        fileWriter.close();
        File file=new File("test.txt");
        System.out.println("file size=" +  file.length());

    }

}
```

This example demonstrates that if you are using a file writer you can obtain its size in realtime while writing and with the writer open. If you want to save space you can zip the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for being slightly off-topic:

Does it have to be in Java?  Depending on how you get your feed data, this sounds like a job for a fairly simple shell script to me (`grep` or `fgrep` for checking for keywords, `gzip` for compressing...)

Comment: I think best to stick to Java, as I know Java fairly well, and everything else is written in Java